# using measure theory in a proof of invariance of domain

Tags: measure-theory

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13

Terence Tao, in the blog cited above, derives invariance of domain
from the fixed point theorem
without reliance on algebraic-topology. He does, however, appeal to measure theory
for a result that I am unable to replicate. If I understand him he asserts:

If $P$ is a polynomial in $
\mathbb{R}^n$ then there exists an $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a $\delta > 0$
such that $P(x+\epsilon y)\neq 0$ for $x\in S^{n-1}$ and $0 < \epsilon < \delta$.

He says this follows from the fact that $S^{n-1}$ and $P(S^{n-1})$ both
have measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Do I interpret him correctly? His assertions sound plausible but I need a hint or two to
make a convincing argument of my own. Is it true that an infinitesimal displacement is
sufficient to make 2 sets of measure 0 disjoint?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of his argument. First, let me recall some of the context of the proof. At this point, Tao has constructed a polynomial $P:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ that is non-zero on $\Sigma_1$, which is some compact set. We have another set $\Sigma_2$, which is of measure $0$, and we would like our polynomial $P$ to be non-zero on $\Sigma_2$ as well. (The precise definitions of $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ are of no importance for this argument.) Tao claims that we can ensure this by perturbing $P$ a little, that is by considering a shifted polynomial
$$
P_{\lambda}(y) = P(y) - \lambda
$$
for some arbitrarily small constant $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Actually, $P_{\lambda}$ will be non-zero on $\Sigma_2$ for almost every $\lambda$ (or, as Tao puts it, for *generic* $\lambda$). This means that the set $E$ of $\lambda$'s such that $0 \in P_{\lambda}(\Sigma_2)$ has measure $0$. Indeed, since $\Sigma_2$ has measure $0$ and $P$ is smooth, the image $P(\Sigma_2)$ has measure $0$. If $\lambda \in E$, then $0 \in P_{\lambda}(\Sigma_2) =P(\Sigma_2)- \lambda$. So $\lambda \in P(\Sigma_2)$. This implies that $E \subset P(\Sigma_2)$. Thus $E$ has measure $0$.

In particular, we can choose $\lambda$ as small as we like. We must choose it small enough so that $P_{\lambda}$ is non-zero on *both* $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$. We know that $P(\Sigma_1)$ does not contain $0$. Since $\Sigma_1$ is compact, its image $P(\Sigma_1)$ is also compact. Hence there is some $\delta$ such that $||P(y)|| > \delta >0$ on $\Sigma_1$. Choosing $\lambda$ such that $|| \lambda || < \delta$, we are sure that $P_{\lambda}$ is also non-zero on $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: You seem to be elaborating Tao's assertion. Can you explain in terms I can understand why I should believe the assertion? I do not know much about polynomials that  map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, and in particular, what their 0's look like.

Comment: To be specific, consider two lines $\sum_{0<k\leq 2}a_{ik}x_k = 0$ cutting the disk $\sum_{0<k\leq 2}x_k^2 \leq 1$. It takes more than a small displacement to keep them from intersecting.

Comment: I can try. It actually doesn't matter that $P$ is a polynomial; this will work for any differentiable map. The point is that a differentiable map sends sets of measure $0$ to sets of measure $0$. Since $\Sigma_2$ has measure $0$, we know that its image has measure $0$ too, so it is a "small" set (in the measure-theoretic sense). This small set might contain $0$, but the idea is that by wiggling it a little we should be able to make it disjoint from $0$. My argument above makes this rigorous. (By the way, are you familiar with measure theory?)

Comment: You are right. It is not possible in general to make two sets of measure $0$ disjoint by an arbitrarily small displacement. But in our situation, one of these set is actually the one-point set $\{ 0 \}$, and this is important in the argument. We could replace $\{ 0 \}$ by any countable set and make this work, but it won't work with _any_ measure $0$ set.

Comment: Could we discuss this in a chat room, say,
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14150/calculus-and-analysis?